# $B_n$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology

I have proven that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}A_n$ is compact,  $A_n=(-1/n,1+1/n)$; for this I have used the fact that $\bigcap A_n = [0,1]$ and the cantor nested interval theorem.

Now I must prove that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_n$ is not compact $B_n=(0, 1+1/n)$. My problem is that I cannot see Bn as an interval, can I solve the exercise in another way?  or can someone give me a hint?

Comment: What do you mean, you "cannot see $B_n$ as an interval"? It clearly is one.

Comment: Also, the title is wrong. The question is whether $\bigcap B_n$ is compact.

Comment: right, I explained wrong .If $\bigcap A_n=[0,1]$ then $\bigcap B_n=$??

Comment: $A_n\neq[0,1].$ $\bigcap A_n=[0,1]$

Comment: sorry, I forgot to write the$\bigcap$

Comment: Choose some numbers near $1$.  For each number you choose, figure out whether it's always in $B_n~\forall n \in \Bbb N$.  You should see quickly what's going on.  Example:  Is $1.1$ always in $B_n$?  How about $0.9$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> I have proven that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}A_n$ is compact,  $A_n=(-1/n,1+1/n)$; for this I have used the fact that $\bigcap A_n = [0,1]$ and the cantor nested interval theorem.

Cantor has nothing to do with the first fact. Indeed the intersection of the $A_n$ equals $[0,1]$ of which you should *know* it is compact (closed and bounded in $\Bbb R$ being one way). Cantor's theorem would apply if the $A_n$ were themselves compact or closed, which are they most definitely are *not*.

Now simple set theory and reasoning tells us that $\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb Z^+} B_n = (0,1]$ which is *not* compact as it is not closed in $\Bbb R$. It's as simple as that. Again, Cantor 's theorem is not applicable (and you cannot prove *non*-compactness with it).

Now just convince yourself of the truth of these identities with infinite intersections.

I think the "point" the exercise is trying to make is: a nested  intersection of **non**-compact sets **can** be compact (by coincidence, really) as with the $A_n$ or **not** (as with the $B_n$). Both are countable, nested decreasing, intersections of open (and non-closed) intervals. You have to judge on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: each subsequent $B_n$ has the same lower bound of 0. Is $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} B_n$ open or closed at that lower bound?